# Make startSignUp Action private in securesocial 3.0-M3/master.snapshot with Play 2.3x

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3, securesocial

I made a custom Registration controller similar to the default Registration controller:

```
class Registration(override implicit val env: RuntimeEnvironment[BasicProfile]) extends medRegistration[BasicProfile]
```

with

```
trait medRegistration[U] extends BaseRegistration[U] {
  ...
  override def startSignUp = Action {
    ...
  }
```

How can I secure startSignUp, since I only want the admin to be able to sign up users, but want the user to be able to complete the signUp process by mailToken.

I have my working standard constraints for normal actions:

```
SecuredAction(WithRole("admin"))
```

But I can't get it to work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made another controller, with new startsignup and starthandlesignup Actions. I had to copy handleStartResult and createToken from MailtokenBasedOperations though.